# PHP casting an expression

Tags: php, casting

Can somebody please explain to me step by step, why does the following code print out `7`?

```
echo (int)((0.7+0.1)*'10th');
```

Comment: that is very interesting: I also tried to force casting with `(int)((0.7 + 0.1)*(int)('10th'))` and it still prints `7`

Comment: What would you *expect* the "correct" result to be? Are you aware of floating point imprecision and that you cannot *expect* any particular result to begin with?

Comment: I don't see any resemblances with the duplicate. And this is not the first time. I guess the permissiveness of people with the high score will kill this site. It is really a pity.

Comment: @deceze, if you remove `(int)` casting you will get `8`, so `7` is really unexpected result.

Comment: @Rizier123 it's not duplicate. `http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php` have "big red warning" with your example @ShiroiOkami

Comment: @sevavietl You will get a floating point number which is so close to 8 that it's displayed rounded up as 8, but when you floor the value (cast to int, same thing here) it's *actually* 7…

Comment: @deceze, I see. thanks.

Comment: @deceze Thank you, it's clear now!

Comment: @Yupik I will read it, thank you!